# I see only ?-s when using 2 pickerviews in Swift on the same view controller, how to fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I have been trying to figure out this problem for hours, now I have only one small problem remaining:

I use 2 UI pickers on one view controller, and when I try to select one (aka I'm clicking into the textfield) all I see is question marks, but if I click on one of them, the text will appear in the textfield. I just don't see what am I choosing in the picker.

I already tried using normal pickerviews, I used tags for each pickers, but nothing seemed to work. I know how it should work, I watched a ton of tutorials, but something is still missing. Can you please help me? Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class SelectionViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var genderTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lifeStyleTextField: UITextField!

    let picker1 = UIPickerView()
    let picker2 = UIPickerView()

    var genders = ["Male", "Female"]
    var lifeStyle = ["Sitting", "Normal", "Active"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        picker1.dataSource = self
        picker1.delegate = self

        picker2.dataSource = self
        picker2.delegate = self

        genderTextField.inputView = picker1
        lifeStyleTextField.inputView = picker2
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView : UIPickerView!) -> Int{
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        if pickerView == picker1 {
            return genders.count
        } else {
            return lifeStyle.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if pickerView == picker1 {
            return genders[row]
        } else if pickerView == picker2{
            return lifeStyle[row]
        }
        else {
            print("No pickerview selected.")
        }
        return ("Pickeview not selected")
    }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if pickerView == picker1 {
                genderTextField.text = genders[row]
                self.view.endEditing(false)
            } else if pickerView == picker2{
                lifeStyleTextField.text = lifeStyle[row]
                self.view.endEditing(false)
            }
            else {
                print("Love love love I want your love")
            }
        }
}
```

And here's the thing I see:

[image]

Comment: You have two numberOfComponents methods. The second one you should remove

Comment: @LeoDabus having 2 NumberofComps was a mistake which remained in my code, sorry. I removed the last one and returned 1 but it still didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Fix your titleForRow method signature. Add the missing underscore

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, the _ was missing... Thank you for your instant help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this signature ( missed _ )

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
```

and `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`  should return 1

Comment: So if that’s all you should close it as a typo

Comment: @LeoDabus no it's not a typo such error is trending since swift 3

Comment: So close it as a duplicate

Comment: OMG thank you @Sh_Khan this solved my issue. A _ was missing. TT